# How to retrieve variable from a request body

Tags: jmeter

In my JMeter script I have a request which uses a token as part of the **request** body:

[image]

I've got a regex extractor to retrieve this value but I can't seem to get it back. I've tested using **all the "Field to check"** values e.g. Request Header etc. The regext I'm using is "token=(.*?)"

[image]

This token is needed as other calls explicitly reference it and I need to pass them this variable

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Switch "Field to check" to `URL` as in your case the token is not in the request body, it's in URL's [Query String](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)
2. Amend your regular expression to look like: `token=(.*)`

   [image]

This way you will get the token value into the `${TOKEN}` JMeter Variable.

More information:

- [JMeter: Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter-Using-RegEx-(Regular-Expression-Extractor)-with-JMeter)
- [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)

Comment: I'd tested against URL but it was my regex which was incorrect. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Query parameters are part of the url, so choose URL as `Field to check`

Also you are building the URL, so can't you use save the token value before?